# Make h264 source seekable

Tags: gstreamer

I have a h.264 stream that I’m trying to make it seakable

Once the stream is ended video is recorded however by default, it won't be seekable. I know by making the source streamable it disables seekability however I was wondering if there’s a way to inject index info at the end of the stream or is there a anyway to make the video seekable in some other way?

How I'm setting up GSTBus:

```
eosBus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
   gst_bus_add_signal_watch (eosBus);
   g_signal_connect (eosBus, "message", (GCallback) message_cb, pipeline);
```

The way I'm handling EOS:

```
static void gst_native_stop_recording (JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
        gst_element_send_event(pipeline, gst_event_new_eos());
        gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
        //unlink elements
```

Here's how I setup the calback message function (which is never triggered)

```
static void message_cb (GstBus * bus, GstMessage * message, gpointer user_data)
{
  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (message)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS: {
        GST_DEBUG("Got EOS\n");
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information about what you are trying to do? GStreamer pipeline?

Comment: @YunieskyVasconcelo Apologies for the late reply, here's the [pipeline](https://imgur.com/a/y9N6N) for recording videos.

Comment: Do you properly stop the pipeline through EOS?

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Hey, I edited my original post, you can see how I'm trying to handle EOS

Comment: Not sure. But I would not pause the pipeline after sending EOS. Does EOS hit the bus? I would stop the pipeline after EOS has hit the bus - not before.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch No, EOS never registers.